# Boolean column in HSQLDB with default value

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have having trouble getting HSQLDB to create a table with a boolean column.
It seems every time I try to specify a default, I get the exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: DEFAULT
```

I can create this problem even with this trivial table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

According to the documentation, I should be able to do this!

See columnDefinition in http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section

Have I misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the HSQLDB [doc](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_table-section) provided, the correct syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL
);
```

i.e. The order matters in the SQL